# How do I construct such layout from XML?

Tags: xml, android-layout

**Layout**

[image: page layout]

I have tried my best to make it as similar to the layout but it looks a bit odd and I wasn't able to link it with other pages that I have created. Please help me out with the code. Your assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: XML is text and you should be able to open the XML with a text editor to compare xml files.  I like generating XML files using Powershell.  Can create any xml that is needed with PS.  But need the format.